# add space between section and subsection in TOC?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, tocloft

Is it possible to create more space before a new section in TOC?
I would like more space where the arrows are:
[image]

I tried using `\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip3pt}` - but that does not give the effect I'm looking for.

```
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0.7in}{0.5in} %laver subsubsections indtrykket mindre.        
 %\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vskip3pt}
%\renewcommand\cftsecafterpnum{\vskip5pt}
\singlespacing
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-1em} 
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip-15pt}
\tableofcontents{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

Comment: Do you want to have this skip for any `section`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the skip should be increased before any `\section` entry `\cftbeforesecskip` is the right command to be changed.

Adjust the value to your needs.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\cftbeforesecskip}{10pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Delklusion}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{Another subsection}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to you make so the "delkonklusion" is without spacing before? :)
Your setup/layout is exact what i want - but my add spacing before "delkonklusion" as well...

Comment: @LAmtorp: Untested: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Delkonklusion}` -- give it a try please